# R sqldf parsing/case when statement for unsupported characters

Tags: r, sqldf

R gives me an error due to unsupported character in sqldf,
For e.g. when I type following:

```
sqldf("select *, 
case symptom
when 'Bell's palsy' or 'Facial pain' or 'Facial paralysis' then 'neuropathy'
end as Adverse_event from data")
```

The error is due to `"'"` in the Bell's word. Is there any work to bypass this error? And also correctly capturing this occurrence in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just double up the single quote apostrophe's in your query, e.g.

```r
sql <- "select *, case symptom
                      when 'Bell''s palsy' then 'neuropathy'
                      when 'Facial pain' then 'neuropathy' 
                      when 'Facial paralysis' then 'neuropathy'
                  end as Adverse_event
        from data"
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

However, I would have used `WHERE IN (...)` here:

```r
sql <- "SELECT *, CASE WHEN symptom IN ('Bell''s palsy', 'Facial pain', 'Facial paralysis')
                       THEN 'neuropathy' END AS Adverse_event
        FROM data"
sqldf(data)
```